# Slow KNN within fixed radius search (PostGIS) - ST_DWITHIN vs KNN

Tags: postgis, distance, knn, st-dwithin

**Ask:**
I want to return all customers matching certain characteristics within a 50 mile radius of the incoming zip code. This query takes just over a second to complete, and that's because of this line:

```
(customers_at_locations.latlong <-> ST_Point(-118.38154, 34.09401)::geography) / 1609.34) < 50
```

My original query did this using ST_DWITHIN but that completely hangs (it ran for 7min before I stopped it):

```
(ST_DWITHIN(customers_at_locations.latlong, ST_Point(-118.38154, 34.09401)::geography, 80467.0 ))
```

I think what makes this query more complicated is the order by distance AND ID at the bottom (which is needed for pagination reasons). Without it the index is utilized and the result is pretty fast. I'm not sure how to add that secondary order by and STILL use the spatial gist index. I came across this article: https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/wont-you-be-my-neighbor-quickly-finding-who-is-nearby and added a multicolumn gist index: ["latlong", "id", "location_type", "customer_id"], name: "customers_at_locations_latlong_search_idx", hoping that that would take care of the order by and join on columns, but it doesn't get used --
customers_at_locations_zip_search_idx does. Note that all my latlong columns are type geography.

Query and query plan:

https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/d5f6af383a1bgc2b#plan

My indexes:

customers ~6 million rows:

```
t.index ["assoc_id"], name: "index_customers_on_assoc_id"  
t.index ["characteristics", "updated_at", "assoc_id"], name: "customers_search_idx"  
t.index ["characteristics"], name: "index_customers_on_charcteristics", using: :gin  
t.index ["updated_at"], name: "index_customers_on_updated_at"
```

customers_at_locations ~8 million rows:

```
t.index ["location_type", "updated_at", "customer_id", "address_id"], name: "customers_at_locations_zip_search_idx"
t.index ["latlong", "id", "location_type", "customer_id"], name: "customers_at_locations_latlong_search_idx", using: :gist
t.index ["latlong"], name: "index_customers_at_locations_on_latlong", using: :gist
t.index ["address_id"]
t.index ["updated_at"]
```

addresses ~3 million rows:

```
t.index ["latlong"], name: "index_addresses_on_latlong", using: :gist  
t.index ["row_id"], name: "index_addresses_on_row_id"  
t.index ["updated_at"], name: "index_addresses_on_updated_at"
t.index ["zip_code"], name: "index_addresses_on_zip_code"
```